# Hacer modo oscuro, hacerlo mas eficiente

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

como podría poner este código sin duplicar líneas de código? en el apartado de la función knowTheme() esta exactamente igual que en changerTheme() pero al contrario, así me funciona bien, pero tengo la mosca detrás de la cabeza  por haber duplicado las líneas de código

```
flexSwitchCheckReverse.addEventListener("click", function () {
  changerTheme();
})

function changerTheme() {
  if (parseBool(localStorage.darkMode) === false) {
    fondoTarjeta.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("bg-info")
      element.classList.add("tarjetaFondo")
    })
    bg.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("bg")
      element.classList.add("bgNegativo")
    })
    link.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("text-black")
      element.classList.add("text-white")
    })
  } else {
    fondoTarjeta.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.add("bg-info")
      element.classList.remove("tarjetaFondo")
    })
    bg.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.add("bg")
      element.classList.remove("bgNegativo")
    })

    link.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("text-white")
      element.classList.add("text-black")
    })
  }
  localStorage.darkMode = !parseBool(localStorage.darkMode);
}

function knowTheme() {
  if (parseBool(localStorage.darkMode) === true) {
    fondoTarjeta.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("bg-info");
      element.classList.add("tarjetaFondo")
    })
    bg.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("bg")
      element.classList.add("bgNegativo")
    })
    link.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("text-black")
      element.classList.add("text-white")
    })

    flexSwitchCheckReverse.setAttribute('checked','')

  }else{
    fondoTarjeta.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.add("bg-info")
      element.classList.remove("tarjetaFondo")
    })
    bg.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.add("bg")
      element.classList.remove("bgNegativo")
    })

    link.forEach((element) => {
      element.classList.remove("text-white")
      element.classList.add("text-black")
    })
  }
}
```

nose si me explico bien, esto es para cambiar al modo oscuro y para que al refrescar esté el modo oscuro si estaba puesto.

he pensado en hacer otra variable isDarkMode en  localStorage, pero ahora mismo no caigo en como implementarlo

Comment: ¿Mover el código duplicado a una función?

Answer (score 0):

Para casos parecidos a estos yo creo una estructura para guardar los valores, de esta manera

```
const Clases = [
    { selector: '.fondoTarjeta', darkModeClass: 'bg-info', ligthModeClass: 'tarjetaFondo'},
    { selector: '.bg', darkModeClass: 'bg', ligthModeClass: 'bgNegativo' }
];
```

Esta estructura me permite modificar, agregar y quitar elementos de manera fácil.
Con esto, la función changerTheme, quedaría así:

```
function changerTheme() { 
    let isDarkmode = parseBool(localStorage.darkMode);
    Clases.forEach((item) => { 
        document.querySelectorAll(item.selector).forEach((element) => { 
            if (isDarkmode) { //Esto es más eficiente dejarlo una linea arriba, pero me parece que dentro es más legible
                element.classList.replace(item.ligthModeClass, item.darkModeClass);
            }
            else{
                element.classList.replace(item.darkModeClass, item.ligthModeClass);
            }
        });
    });
    localStorage.darkMode = !isDarkmode;
}
```

Ahora para el caso particular de cambiar de modo osucuro a claro, me parece mejor alternativa tener una clase en el body que identifique el modo, y luego que todas las reglas css deriven de esas clases. Con ello solo cambiar la clase del body con js y cambia todo. Otro método sería ocupar variables de css y cambiar las variables según el modo.

Otra opción es ocupar un prefijo con un guion para diferenciar las clases y sus modos, por ejemplo la clase "Oscuro-fondo" y "Claro-Fondo", "Claro-Texto", etc. Con esto puedes el selector [class|="Oscuro"] lo que te retorna todos los elementos que tengan la clase Oscuro y que empiecen con "Oscuro-", entonces creas una función como esta:

```
function changerTheme() { 
    let isDarkmode = localStorage.darkMode;
    let prefix = isDarkmode ? "Oscuro" : "Claro";
    document.querySelectorAll(`[class|="${prefix}"]`).forEach((element) => { 
        element.classList.forEach((clase) => { 
            if (clase.includes(prefix)) {
                let nuevaClase = clase.replace(prefix, isDarkmode ? "Claro" : "Oscuro");
                element.classList.replace(clase, nuevaClase);
            }
        });
    });
    localStorage.darkMode= !isDarkmode;
}
```